# Action/Controller Url from Service

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.net Core Webapi project, and I have a DI Service I register in `ConfigureServices` and then execute in the Configure.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddTransient<SeedingDatabase>();
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, SeedingDatabase seeder)
{
    ...
    seeder.PopulateFakeData();
}
```

In the `populateFakeData` method, I am adding a list of services my application will expose. I would like to provide those record with a URL to the action/controller from within this method, without having to hardcode the URL.

For example, say I have a class

```
namespace api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyServiceController : ControllerBase
    {
        ...

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<...>> MyAwesomeService()
        {
            return ...
        }
    }
}
```

I could hardcode a reference to this as `{ROOT_URL}/api/myservice/myawesomeservice`. But that's kind of bad as if the route changes on the container or action, then this is no longer valid.

Is there a way I can dynamically lookup the expected route of the action, specifying the action in code, not a string. Something like `getRouteUri(MyServiceController::MyAwesomeService)`

At the very least I will probably have to provide the host (https://somedomain.com/) as a config option, and pass that to the into the Seeding service (or use more DI), but the relative URL of the action should be obtainable right?

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to send a specific HTTP request to seed the database? Like GET https://example.com/db/seed ? If so, then you can't do that from `Startup.Configure`. Because the configure action creates the HTTP pipeline (how an incoming HTTP request will be handled). You'll have to use a controller and inject `SeedingDatabase` in the constructor. In the controller you can check the `Request` object and get the full URL if you need that too.

Comment: @JosseanYamil I have updated the question, it was poorly described before. I hope this is better.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`IUrlHelper.Action()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_System_String_) method to get the route?
You could do something like `string url = Url.Action("MyAwesomeService", "MyService")` in a controller. The `url` variable will be equal to `"api/myservice/myawesomeservice"` in your example. If you need the `IUrlHelper` outside a controller, then you have to inject it in your service.

Comment: I have seen it, however its the injection of it as a service thats the hard bit. Here is an article that gets close, but I don't use `useMvc` I use `useControllers` so not exactly sure where to get the router info from.
https://codeopinion.com/generating-links-with-urlhelper-outside-of-asp-net-core/